# Injeção de Dependência em Classes que não tenho acesso

Tags: java, spring-boot, injeção-de-dependência

Olá, como vão?

Como posso fazer injeção de dependência em uma classe que não tenho acesso, ou seja, não posso dizer em cima da classe que ela é um java bean (@Component).

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Piovezan. Minha pergunta não foi bem redigida. Desculpe-me. O impasse que estou é: possuo um arquivo java que não tenho acesso. E gostaria de marca-lo como @Component, para que assim eu possa faz injeção de dependência. Há algum jeito para isso? Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso através do [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) usando o [getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html#getAutowireCapableBeanFactory--) em conjunto com [autowireBeanProperties()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBeanProperties-java.lang.Object-int-boolean-):

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;

private void foo(){
    ClasseQueNaoTemAcesso umaClasseQueNaoTenhoAcesso = new ClasseQueNaoTemAcesso();
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
    .autowireBeanProperties(umaClasseQueNaoTenhoAcesso,
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_AUTODETECT, true);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Brenno!